# Lossless compression for video in opencv

Tags: opencv, video-processing

I am working on a video processing project that involves some sort of encryption using simple XOR operation of a given frame from camera with a key image  and finally store the video file.
And for decryption phase the XOR operation with the same image will get the original frames. But the problem is while I decrypt the frame appears to be very noisy and found out that its because of the lossy image compression foramt I used while storing. Is there any other lossless image compression foramts for opencv??

Comment: try saving the image as `tiff`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on windows you can use `CV_FOURCC_PROMPT` as the second parameter of `VideoWriter` constructor - it will allow you to choose codec from list and set various options. Just for test you can use `uncompressed avi (aka full frames [not compressed])`. It will produce huge files, but should work fine.

Note that HighGui is “meant as a simple tool for experimentation”, so it may not provide the functionality you are looking for. If so you will have to use some other library and give it each frame processed by opencv.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [old page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs) of OpenCV:

> There are several lossless video compressors available. No single one however is supported on all platforms at the same time. Look for HuffYUV, CorePNG, Motion PNG or Motion JPEG2000.

Recent [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html#the-structure-of-a-video) mentions a couple of alternatives as well, like **JPG2000** and [**LAGS**](https://lags.leetcode.net/codec.html) (*Lagarith Lossless Codec*).

Some time ago [someone posted a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598462/lossless-avi-encoding-on-linux) explaining how he had used OpenCV and FFmpeg to render videos with lossless compression.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation says
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ad59c61d8881ba2b2da22cff5487465b5

> Most codecs are lossy. If you want lossless video file you need to use
> a lossless codecs (eg. FFMPEG FFV1, Huffman HFYU, Lagarith LAGS,
> etc...)
>
> If FFMPEG is enabled, using codec=0; fps=0; you can create an
> uncompressed (raw) video file.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian Linux (using ffmpeg):

```
int width = 640;
int height = 480;
bool isColor = true;
string outFName = "out.avi";

Size frameSize = Size(width, height);
int fourcc = VideoWriter::fourcc('p', 'n', 'g', ' ');

outputVideo.open(outFName, fourcc, cap.get(CAP_PROP_FPS), frameSize, isColor));
```