# CV2 image to video changes RGB values

Tags: python, image, video, opencv

I am trying to write jpg's to a video using cv2. I define a mock image as such:

```
fake_image = np.array([[[122, 131, 140]] * 416] * 416).astype(np.uint8)
```

Next, I write this to a video using:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('mock_video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 1, (416, 416))
out.write(fake_image)
out.release()
```

Then, I try to read the frames of my video:

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture('mock_video.mp4')
return_value, frame = vid.read()
```

And now the rgb values have changed! Rather than being `[122, 131, 140]`, they are now `[118, 129, 137]`!

Why is this happening and can I stop it from happening?

Edit: yes i know cv2 uses BGR, that is not what is going on (it is not the case that the order of channels is reversed)

Comment: ^ that is not what is going on... please read the question :/

Comment: `mp4` similar to `jpg` changes pixels to better compress it. For images you could use `.png` but for video it may not be good solution.

Comment: on Wikipedia you can see list of [lossless video codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Lossless_video_compression) and you would have to check in `cv2` documentation if it can use some of these codecs.

Comment: Using Google I found: [Lossless compression for video in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728939/lossless-compression-for-video-in-opencv) and [How to write lossless video in Python](https://www.imagetracking.org.uk/2017/12/how-to-write-lossless-video-in-python/)